# Is there a way to automatically cross-link questions between SE sites?

Tags: discussion, support, cross-posting

Recently I had a question about the Akra-Bazzi Master Theorem from the study of algorithms that I posted on Math Stackexchange.

All of the tags seemed to be relatively popular on Math SE, so I thought it would make more sense to ask on Math Stackexchange, since I have more reputation here and figured that my question would be taken more seriously here than on computer science.

Although the subject is applied primarily only to computer science, the problem is formulated in purely mathematical terms (in my opinion).

Should I ask a moderator to migrate it to Computer Science?

And apparently there is also a Computational Science stack exchange?

What is the point of having questions about algorithms being asked on at least three different stackexchange websites, where reputation from one does not transfer between site to site?

Answer (score 6):

> I have more reputation here and figured that my question would be taken more seriously

This is not a good way to choose a site to post on.

Computational Science has a rather different topic, as you could see from its [on topic](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. Your Master Theorem homework does not belong there.

It's okay on Computer Science or on Math; there is an overlap between sites. Still, cross-posting is frowned upon (I expressed my frown by downvoting all three copies).

Comment: @William: There are still rules for cross-posting. Like waiting a little bit. Being impatient is a huge turn off, and it's annoying. It means there is duplicated work on several sites, and that implies that you don't appreciate the people who answer you *for free*. My usual analogy involves ordering pizza from several different places at the same time, just in hope that one of them arrives within 30 minutes. That's not how things should work.

Comment: @William The onus is on you to make it easy and attractive to answer. Having to follow links to other places to make sure one isn't duplicating work isn't that. Whence it is generally only acceptable to crosspost after some time.

Comment: Also, "to feel self-righteous and attempt to justify an argument which does not make any coherent sense" is top-notch irony right there after your five-comment plea.

Comment: @William [Read this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/262767) [And this.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21237/10014)

Comment: @William this site is very lenient towards cross-posting relative to others. Not few sites take an attitude of: "No cross-posts. Period."  Indeed, it seems you already experienced this on [cs.se].  Posting right away on several sites is a nuisance even with links, especially on high-paced sites.